# Update table using join- error ORA-00933

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

I have a table need to update by joining condition with another table.

`UPDATE a
 SET a.REF_ID = b.NEW_REF_ID
 FROM CRS_CUSTOMERS a 
 INNER JOIN DAY0_SUBSET b
 ON a.CUSTOMER_ID = b.CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID;`

The above statement just complain `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`, syntax error highlighted on the line `FROM CRS_CUSTOMERS a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a nested sub-select :

```
UPDATE CRS_CUSTOMERS a
 SET a.REF_ID = ( SELECT b.NEW_REF_ID
                   FROM DAY0_SUBSET b
                  WHERE a.CUSTOMER_ID = b.CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID );
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/038174/1)

Comment: your script is correct, but i wonder it will will all records in CRS_CUSTOMERS. For example, if i just need to REF_ID of a particular CUSTOMER ID?

Comment: @user2102665 not all records, but an individual record, because of `WHERE a.CUSTOMER_ID =`. Update for only matching `a.CUSTOMER_ID = b.CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID`, individually.

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid UPDATE syntax.

Suggest you try something along the lines of [can't test it currently, and it assumes that ref_id and customer_id don't exist on the day0_subset table]

```
UPDATE CRS_CUSTOMERS
  SET REF_ID =
    (select b.NEW_REF_ID
       from DAY0_SUBSET b
       where b.current_customer_id = customer_id)
  where CUSTOMER_ID in (select b.CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID from DAY0_SUBSET b)
```